# Building Triangles with for loops

Tags: java

The `buildTomb(int height)` method will take an integer parameter that represents the height of the pyramid that should be built in the pharaoh’s honor.  This method will print out a representation of the pyramid as shown in the examples below.

Example​:

```
Pharaoh p2 = new Pharaoh(“Rameses”, 7); 
p2.buildTomb(5);

    *      
   ***  
  ***** 
 ******* 
*********
```

Example:

```
Pharaoh p3 = new Pharaoh(“Jim”, 3);    
p3.buildTomb(3);

    *      
   ***  
  *****
```

Example:

```
Pharaoh p4 = new Pharaoh(“Pickle”, 3); 
p4.buildTomb(1);

    *      
   ***
```

I am failing to get those results here is the code i already have

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Pharaoh here.
 * 
 */
public class Pharaoh
{
    private String name;
    private int greatness;

    public Pharaoh(String n, int g)
    {
        name = n;
        greatness = g;
    }

    public void buildTomb( int height)
    {
        if(height > greatness)
            System.out.println("(PEASANT REVOLT)");

        if(height <= 2)
            height = 2;

        if(height >= 2 && height <= greatness)
        {
            int x = height;

            for(int m = 0; m < 2 * x - 1; m++) //for upper star
                System.out.print(" ");

            System.out.println("*");

            for(int j = 1; j <= x; j += 1)
            {
                for(int i = 1; i <= x - j; i += 1)
                    System.out.print("  ");

                for(int k = 1; k <= 2 * j; k += 1)
                    System.out.print("* ");

                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println( name + " 's TOMB ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See any patterns? 
`Astericks: Top -> 1, Next -> 3, Next -> 5`
`Spaces: Top -> 4, Next -> 3, Next -> 2, Next -> 1`

Comment: `I'm failing to get those results` What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that my output is different

Comment: Ok well we aren't just going to answer your homework for you

Comment: What you're going to want to do here is to fix your code to produce the correct output.

Answer (score 1):

**Use functions to compartmentalize the problem.**

For this function, you have a number of lines that you need to print.  For each line, you need to know two things: the number of spaces to print and the number of asterisks to print.  Write a function to calculate each of these values, given the line number.

Once you have done that, simply use those functions to do the work.  If you have bugs, you'll find them when you look at the result.  Trial and error should get you the rest of the way.

Answer (score 1):

All lines should be printed with the same code. There's nothing special about the top/first line.

First, you need to recognize the pattern, as mentioned by Riley Carney:

> See any patterns?
>   `Astericks: Top -> 1, Next -> 3, Next -> 5`
>   `Spaces: Top -> 4, Next -> 3, Next -> 2, Next -> 1`

You have a loop of rows (your `j` loop), counting from `1` to `height` (inclusive).

Now look at the pattern, and see if you can calculate the two values.

For spaces (indentation), the bottom row has 0 spaces, and the rows above have 1 more than the row below. This means the values go from `height - 1` down to `0`, or in other words:

```
spaces = height - row
```

For stars (`*`), the top row has 1 star, and every row below that has 2 more. This means the values are `1`, `3`, `5`, ..., or in other words:

```
stars = row * 2 - 1
```

Now, when you print, you should only print a single spaces, and you should not print a space after the stars, because you're currently printing these 6(!) lines:

```
         *
        * * 
      * * * * 
    * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

when you should have been printing these 5(!) lines:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```